# Waiting image inside a JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, java

I have this function bellow:

```
    function consult(number, sequence){
        form = document.forms[1];

        form.number.value = number;
        form.sequence.value = sequence;

        form.submit();

    }
```

After a submit, a Java Action is called.

```
@Override
    public ActionForward perform(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ApplicationException, SystemException {

        MyForm myForm=  (MyForm ) form;

        MyDelegate.getInstance().cancel(myForm);

        return mapping.findForward("cancel");
    }
```

Is possible while this function are being executed, put a simple gif waiting ?

Like this:

[image]

This task can lead seven seconds.

Comment: Javascript != Java. If you are using Java can you show us your Java code?

Comment: yes, no problem, I will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finish in this way:

```
function consult(number, sequence){
    //Here you call your loading
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="loading.gif" /> Wainting...</h1>' });

    form = document.forms[1];

    form.number.value = number;
    form.sequence.value = sequence;

    form.submit();

}
```

Using Jquery:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can have this gif initially with:

```
opacity: 0;
display: none;
```

The time before loading the submit method, it changes the opacity and display for:

```
opacity: 1;
display: block;
```

when the function ends, you change the gif to the initial state.

Comment: I want to show this Gif, like an "alert", how I have to show this image in pure JavaScript, I know how to do this using http://malsup.com/jquery/block/, but I don´t know with pure JavaScript. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With its own Javascript you can pick up the elements contained in the drawing through: 
document.getElementById ("myId"); (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)
if possible in your situation. if it is, you can change the opacity and his display in the JS code.